# Google Calendar Node.js quickstart Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 for concurrent users

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have successfully implemented Google Calendar's quickstart guide for Node.js:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs

Its all working as expected for a single user at a time, however if a second user accesses the page while the first user is still using it they get the error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000`

I can see this happens because `client = await authenticate(...)` starts a server on port 3000, so when the second user enters the page this code attempts to start another server on the same port and therefore errors.

So what should I be doing here? This seems flawed for a real world system. Plus the only `Authorised Redirect URI` seems to be `http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback` due to whatever the `google-cloud/local-auth` package is doing.

I need a solution that works for our production environment with many concurrent users.